# Find last stored commited offset in low level consumer

Tags: php, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi following is the code for my consumer,

```
    $conf->set('group.id','commonqueue2');
    $conf->set('offset.store.method', 'broker');

    $rk = new \RdKafka\Consumer($conf);
    $rk->addBrokers($kafka_servers);

    $topicConf = new \RdKafka\TopicConf();

    $topicConf->set('auto.commit.interval.ms',1000);
    $topicConf->set('offset.store.method', 'broker');
    $topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'smallest');

    $topic = $rk->newTopic("registration17", $topicConf);

    $topic->consumeStart(0,RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED); 

    while (true) {

        $message = $topic->consume(0,1000);

        //store offset to broker
        $topic->offsetStore($message->partition,$message->offset);

        $message_offset = $message->offset;
        echo $message_data = $message->payload;

    }//end of while loop
```

In the above program how can i find the last stored offset before executing following code

```
$topic->consumeStart(0,RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to get the latest offsets:
1. From zookeeper Shell
   By using the coomand get /consumers//offsets//num_of_partitions
For the help,use this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper

2.To retrieve the latest offset,we can even use the command: bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group  --zookeeper : --topic